# How to have the same values for duplicated items in Power Query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I've come across a scenario where I have duplicate values in the column **`ID without letters`** I'm trying to ensure that these duplicated IDs also have the same values in the **`Stock Unit`**, **`Type`** and **`Has Types`** columns.

Apologise as I'm still relatively new to Power Query and I've been exploring solutions but haven't quite figured it out yet. If anyone has ideas on how to tackle this, I would really appreciate your insights. Please find the tables below for your reference. Thank you.

[image: Table]

[image: Desired Table]

Comment: So how do one determine whether its a duplicate, lets say if there is `B-1` or `C-1` then what shall happen, how will one know whether the `1` is the duplicate of `A-1` or `B-1` or `C-1`. There is not enough information in your post. Clear those clarities with few more examples.

Comment: If I knew exactly what the values in those other columns should be then I would just 1) remove those 3 columns and then 2) add those 3 columns back with what I want them to be. Anything else and you'll have to dive into the M language.

Comment: @newt335  ,,, [edit] the post & re load the screen shots ,,,, since I'm unable to see the larger view ( click to view in separate windows) ,,,  help us to realize the correct situation !!

Comment: Edit your post to include your data **as text** which can be copy/pasted. Also include at least a screenshot of your desired output given the data you have posted.